# Does xdocument load the whole xml document?

Tags: .net, xml, parsing, load, linq-to-xml

I am developing a webpage where I want to parse and XML snippet in a string. I am doing this via XDocument.Load method.

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(New StringReader(strXML))
```

where `strXML` is the xml snippet.

What I want to know is - does the load method load the whole snippet in memory? If that's the case...my program would  slow down considerably if there are 200-300 users logged in at the same time.

Would using `XDocument.parse` be a better option? How is it different from `XDocument.Load`

I am not very keen on using XMLReader for the same.

Comment: Take a look at : 1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345532(v=vs.110).aspx 2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Parse would be more efficient. And I would not worry about 200-300 users.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much the same, but Parse will not require you to do anything special with the XML string. Behind the scenes, the .Net Framework will do it for you:

```
public static XDocument Parse(string text, LoadOptions options)
{
  using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(text))
  {
    XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = XNode.GetXmlReaderSettings(options);
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create((TextReader) stringReader, xmlReaderSettings))
      return XDocument.Load(reader, options);
  }
}
```

The above is decompiled source of the Parse method.